# RegExp for every beginnig word, in Autocomplete jQuery

Tags: regex, autocomplete

I have autocomplete with 10 000+ items,
every item have 4 words,
and I want to match only the beginning of EVERY words in item

This RegExp match only beginning of every item:

```
var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
```

Is here solution?

Comment: Replace `^` with `\\b`

Comment: thanx very much